# É possível utilizar ficheiros locais para essa biblioteca Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou a utilizar 3 scripts para criar um gráfico line chart utilisando graphael. Utilizei o script online. O problema é que quero utilizar sem acesso a ficheiros externos.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.0.0/raphael-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphael/0.5.0/g.raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphael/0.5.0/g.line-min.js"></script>
```

Copiei o código para 3 ficheiro locais diferentes. Mas tive um outro problema, pois são ficheiro muito grandes e nem utilizo metade do código no meu exemplo, e receio que isto torne o carregamento da minha página mais demorado. Existe esses ficheiros mais curtos, com menos código? É preciso mesmo utilizar estas 3 bibliotecas?

Exemplo do meu gráfico: http://jsfiddle.net/aNJxf/23/

Comment: acredito que a versão que está usando já é a menor por ser .min